# What is the difference between echo "${array[@]}" echo "${array[*]}" in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I get the same results with both `echo "${array[@]}"` and `echo "${array[*]}"`.
If I do:
`mkdir fakemusic; touch fakemusic/{Beatles,Stone,Ramones,Doors}{001..199}; cd fakemusic`.
Then `_msc=(*)`
These two commands give me identical output:

```
echo "${_msc[@]}"  
echo "${_msc[*]}"
```

So what is the difference between them.

Comment: both are same unless you enclose them in double quotes `""`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell expands `"${_msc[@]}"` as separate strings, while it expands `"${_msc[*]}"` as a single string, with the items separated by space by default. You can't see the difference with `echo` because it also uses a space as a separator. Here's an example with `printf`:

```
$ printf "%s;%s;%s\n" "${_msc[@]}"
a;b;c
$ printf "%s;%s;%s\n" "${_msc[*]}"
a b c;;
```

The shell variable `IFS` controls which character is used as the separator. If you change it you can see the difference with `echo` too:

```
$ IFS='|'
$ echo "${_msc[*]}"    # shell expands to a single string
a|b|c
$ echo "${_msc[@]}"    # shell expands to a separate string
a b c
```

Comment: Thanks @Joni that is what I thought but could not "see" the difference.  The printf example was perfect.